# Merge rows if Column A, B, and C all match (Excel)?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table in power query which includes ID numbers, form name, form date, questions and answers. In power query I pivoted the question column so each question is an individual columns. The results produced many nulls as each row contains a unique answer to one of the questions.

I am trying to combine multiple rows so that there is a single row for every unique combination of ID number, Form Name, and Form Date.

[image: Here is an example of the table I have (top) and the table I need (bottom)]

Note: There are actually 6 questions total, not 3.

As you can see, I need the answers combined to single rows that contain unique combinations of ID Number, Form Name, and Form Date. I've looked up M code and VBA but they all apply to different problems that I'm having difficulty adapting for my needs.

I've tried manipulating in Power Query including the following:

1. Load it to Power Query
2. Select ID, Form Name, and Form Date,
3. Go to the transform tab and the unpivot columns drop down
4. Select unpivot other columns
5. Select the new attribute column
6. Go to the transform tab and select pivot column
7. On the popup select "Value" as the value column --> hit OK
8. On the home tab select "Close and load to" your workbook.

This returns an error message: "Expression.Error: There were too many elements in the enumeration to complete the operation.
Details:
List"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping by the first 3 columns and set the others to aggregate by taking the sum / max / average (they should all give the same result since there's only one non-null).